# Pinched torus generalization

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, surfaces, geometric-topology

The [pinched torus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinched_torus) is homeomorphic to a sphere with two (different) points identified.

         
[image: Wikipedia image]

What is the name and topological structure of the generalization in which $n$ pairs of distinct points of a sphere are identified?  Is the resulting topology independent of the
relationship between the identified pairs of points? In other words, are
all surfaces obtained by identifying $n$ pairs of distinct points homeomorphic to one another?

Thanks for insights/comments/pointers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know that these objects have names, but identifying $n$ pairs of points on $S^2$ corresponds to taking a surface of genus $n$ and pinching off each handle.  Equivalently, take a genus $n$ handlebody and collapse a compression disk bounded by the belt sphere in each handle down to a point, then take the boundary of the resulting object.

To see that all such surfaces (of fixed $n$) are homeomorphic, it suffices to see that for any two finite set of $n$ distinct pairs of distinct points $\{p_1,p_1',p_2,p_2',\ldots,p_n,p_n'\}\subset S^2$ and $\{q_1,q_1',\ldots,q_n,q_n'\}\subset S^2$, there is a homeomorphism $S^2\to S^2$ mapping $p_i\mapsto q_i,\ p_i'\mapsto q_i'$.  Such a homeomorphism will descend to a homeomorphism of quotients.  This can be done by composing a sequence of Dehn twists along narrow annuli, each containing $p_i^{(')}$, $q_i^{(')}$, and none of the other points to be identified.

Spaces similar to this arise in the study of Riemann surfaces: the only way a sequence of surfaces in the moduli space of genus $n$ surfaces can leave all compact sets is by this sort of handle pinching, equivalently regarded as the length of a closed geodesic tending to $0$.  So you might find more information about these pinched surfaces by consulting a treatise on the ideal boundary of moduli space or of Teichmuller space -- I don't know any off the top of my head that treat this in particular, but I'd start by looking in Hubbard's book.

Comment: Thanks, Neal, especially for the proof of homeomorphism!

Comment: You're welcome!  I'm glad the proof was clear.