# Irreducible hypersurfaces vs irreducible polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

I know there exists a bijective correspondence between affine irreducible hypersurfaces and irreducible polynomials. This correspondence associates to each irreducible hypersurface $X=V(f)\subset\mathbb{A}^n$ the irreducible polynomial $g\in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ such that $f=g^k$ (for some $k$) which is unique up to invertible elements. (The field $K$ must be algebraically closed).

Well, the following example seems to contradict the fact I've just recalled. Take $X=V(f)\subset\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$, where $f(x,y)=y^2-x^2(x-1)\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Now, $f$ is irreducible but $X$ seems to have two distinct components, one of which is the point $(0,0)$.

Where is the error? Can you help me please?

Comment: Did you mean to write $\mathbb A^2$ rather than $\mathbb A^3$? In any case, why do you think $(0,0)$ is an irreducible component? There are zeroes of $f(x,y)$ with $x$-coordinates arbitrarily close to $0$...

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Yes, thank you, it is a plane curve. Are you sure of what you said:"there are zeros.......arbitrarily close to 0".....because I got a different picture where the origin looks isolated!

Comment: Over the complexes it is not isolated.

Comment: Are you looking at a picture of the _real_ points? For any value of $x$, the eqn $y^2=x^2(x-1)$ will have at least one complex solution, but no real solution if $x<1$.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Oh I know, that's the problem, I was considering the real trace indeed. But, is it impossible to figure out, how to say, the complex picture?

Comment: Dear Danae, it depends what you mean by "figure out". I would not say it's impossible, but it takes some experience to learn which kinds of geometric intuition you can rely on, and which will lead you astray (as in this case); moreover, you must let _proofs_ guide your _pictures_, rather than vice-versa. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

First let's figure out what the projective closure of the curve looks like. This has homogeneous equation $Y^2 Z = X^3 - X^2 Z$. Crucially, this equation is linear in $Z$: solving for $Z$ we get

$$Z = \frac{X^3}{X^2 + Y^2}$$

from which it follows that

$$(X : Y) \mapsto (X(X^2 + Y^2) : Y (X^2 + Y^2) : X^3)$$

is a rational parameterization of the projective closure of the curve. It is almost, but not quite, an isomorphism: it sends the points $(1 : i)$ and $(1 : -i)$ to the same point $(0 : 0 : 1)$ but away from this point it has inverse given by projection down to the first two coordinates. In other words, over the complex numbers, after adding points at infinity, the curve is topologically a sphere with two points identified (the "kissing banana"). The identified points correspond to the singularity at $(0, 0)$ that is isolated over $\mathbb{R}$: all of the nearby points are being parameterized by points with complex coordinates (even up to scaling).

To figure out what the actual curve looks like we need to remove the points at infinity. These are the points where $Z = 0$ in homogeneous coordinates, so $0 = X^3$ and the only such point is $(0 : 1 : 0)$. Hence the actual curve is topologically a sphere with two points identified and another point missing; in particular, it is connected.

Comment: On the other hand, this hypersurface lives in a family $y^2 = x(x - 1)(x - \lambda)$; it's the singular fiber when $\lambda = 0$. When $\lambda \neq 0, 1$ the projective closure of these curves are elliptic curves, so topologically look like tori, so it's interesting to ask what's happening topologically as $\lambda \to 0$. I think what's happening is that the torus is getting pinched.

Comment: Dear @Qiaochu: yes, that's the correct description of the topology of the degeneration. For anyone who is struggling to visualise this, Joseph O'Rourke's question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118432/pinched-torus-generalization has a nice visualisation of what's going on.